# Correct MVC3 Model type of multiselect box?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

is the correct datatype for a multi-select box in mvc3 DataType.MultilineText? These are ultimately derived from a many-to-many type relationship.

Thanks

Example
A Channel can have multiple Ad Slots, and an Ad Slot can have multiple Channels.

My current model is:

```
[Display(Name = "Ad Slots")]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string[] AdSlots { get; set; }
```

Is that right for a multiselect?

Comment: MulitlineText is  used forTextArea

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC doesn't utilize "types", persay, for DOM elements.  You would utilize the `HtmlHelper.ListBox()` extension method.

This extension method returns a multi-select listbox.

```
@Html.ListBox(
    "YourFormFieldName", 
    new SelectList(new[] { "You can select this one", "and this one" })
)
```

**EDIT**: for a Model, you could use this:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public MultiSelectList YourItems { get; set; }
}
```

And then on a POST you can see which items are selected.

Comment: I am talking about Model type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like `System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList` which takes an `IEnuermable` collection.

Check this article for more info:
http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/tip-of-the-day-198-asp-net-mvc-listbox-controls/

Well with your edit, my answer might not be so helpful since you most likely don't want your Model referencing MVC, but you could maybe do `@Html.ListBox("AdSlots", new MultiSelectList(model.AdSlots))` since its already enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

This Multiline Type means textarea and not multiselect which has a  markup with multiselect as an attribute.